# $L^2$ convergence under different probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $Z$ is a random vector whose range is compact. Let $f,f_n$ be functions of the random vector $Z$. I want to investigate the $L^2$ norm between $f$ and $f_n$ under 2 different probability distributions on $Z$.

Suppose that the two distributions we consider have densities $p_1(z)$ (uniform over the domain of $Z$) and $p_2(z)$. If $\|f_n(z)-f(z)\|_{L^2} \rightarrow 0$ under the density $p_1(z)$, does it imply that $\|f_n(z)-f(z)\|_{L^2} \rightarrow 0$  under the density $p_2(z)$?

I tried using Cauchy-schwarz on $\int |f_n(z)-f(z)|^2 p_2(z) \,dz$ but I can't simplify it further.

I am inclined to believe this is false in general. Are there any well known examples even in real analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z_1$  have uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ and $Z_2$ have density $\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}$ on $(0,1)$. Let $f_n(x)=n^{1/4} I_{(0,\frac  1 n)}$. Then $f_n (Z_1) \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ but $f_n (Z_2)$ does not tend to $0$ in $L^{2}$

Comment: In your terminology we can define $Z(w)=w$ in $(0,1)$  and think of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ both as $Z$ and take the basic measure on $(0,1)$  as Lebesgue measure for $Z_1$ and the one with density $\frac 1 {2\sqrt x}$ for  $Z_2$.